# Read redirected standard output interactively while the process is running

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, asynchronous, cmd

I'm working on a remote shell-like thing for Windows in C#. I have a NetworkStream setup, and a Process wrapper for a instance of the command interpreter. The problem is, I can't read from Standard Output and Standard Error without something messing up. My code for the remote portion is like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Matt_Damon_Remote_Shell
{
    class RemoteEnd
    {
        public System.Diagnostics.Process commandHost
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        TcpListener listener;
        TcpClient client;

        NetworkStream netStream;
        StreamReader netStreamReader;
        StreamWriter netStreamWriter;

        StreamReader outputReader;
        StreamReader errorReader;


        public RemoteEnd()
        {
            initStream();
            initProcess();
        }

        public void receive()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                netStreamWriter.Write(readOutput());
                netStreamWriter.Write(readError());
                netStreamWriter.Flush();
                string next = getNextCommand();
                Console.WriteLine("Remote received: " + next);
                runCommand(next);
            }

        }

        private void initStream()
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 666);
            waitForConnect();
            netStream = client.GetStream();
            netStreamReader = new StreamReader(netStream);
            netStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(netStream);
        }

        private void waitForConnect()
        {
            try
            {
                listener.Start();
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        }

        private void initProcess()
        {
            commandHost = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            //Init process
            commandHost.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            commandHost.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            commandHost.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            commandHost.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            commandHost.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            commandHost.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            commandHost.Start();
            outputReader = new StreamReader(commandHost.StandardOutput.BaseStream);
            errorReader = new StreamReader(commandHost.StandardError.BaseStream);
        }

        private string readOutput()
        {
           //Various implementations described below
        }

        private string readError()
        {
            //Various implementations described below
        }

        private void runCommand(string command)
        {
            if (command == "exit") //this handles the exit function, which doesn't work somehow
            {
                commandHost.Kill(); 
                return;
            }
            commandHost.StandardInput.WriteLine(command);
        }

        private string getNextCommand()
        {
            if (netStream.CanRead)
            {
                return netStreamReader.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First, I tried to grab it asynchronously, but it messed with the sending of the data back. Given enough time, it would send it all back, but I couldn't get it to send everything over the NetworkStream. If I just ran the program, it sent back nothing. If I took the time to add breakpoints and look at the code, it would often send one or two lines back. I couldn't synchronize the event handlers properly, to get the whole thing back. I also tried reading synchronously, but no matter what I tried, be it `ReadLine()`, `ReadBlock()`, or `Read()`, it all blocks my program, and I can't get past the standard cmd startup message. I know there's an end to the streams when I read them, the debugger shows a non-public char buffer with just null-bytes at the end. But, all the methods described above block until, presumably, the process is closed. I can't do that in my situation, as the process has to stay alive to maintain consistent working directories and things like that. Is there a non-blocking way to read synchronously in my situation, or am I going to have to figure out some way for a proper asynchronous read?

Comment: This looks like a classic producer-consumer problem except it is bidirectional. You must avoid blocking by any means, especially when reading the streams. You can block when writing back in either direction at the price of a less smooth user experience.

Comment: @edTarik I've managed to use threads to read off the NetworkStream and StandardOutput. The problem is, I can't find a way to only send data when there is no data left.This leads to problems like me having to put random Thread.Sleeps every where to give it enough time to send. Commands like tree mean I have to type four commands to get the full output. The standard methods for that don't work on StandardOutput because C# has no idea where the end is until the process terminates. Is there a way to figure out where the end of the output for the last sent command is?